# Composition FROM inheritance (Java)

Tags: java, oop

So we all know that composition should usually be favored over inheritance, but what about composition from inheritance? For example, I have a handful of classes that all need access to a handful of other service classes:

```
class A {
  private ClassX serviceClassX;
  private ClassY serviceClassY;
  private ClassZ serviceClassZ;
  // And so on
}
class B {
  private ClassX serviceClassX;
  private ClassY serviceClassY;
  private ClassZ serviceClassZ;
  // And so on
}
class C {
  private ClassX serviceClassX;
  private ClassY serviceClassY;
  private ClassZ serviceClassZ;
  // And so on
}
```

Is there anything wrong with having a Base class that contains all of these service classes where class A,B,C and any other future classes would inherit from? Or is there a better way of doing that like composition from composition where each class would instead contain an instance of Base class which had all the service classes composed in it?

Comment: What is the perceived benefit of your approach? It just sounds more complicated than *either* composition or inheritance to me.

Comment: Basically I wouldn't have to have 10+ declarations at the top of 10+ files that are all completely identical

Comment: I'm all for having a single class, say `MyConnections`, encapsulate `A`, `B`, and `C`. But "composition over inheritance" would say that all of your users should contain a `MyConnections` instance, not inherit from it.

Comment: What you call "composition from composition" could be the [Facade pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade).

Comment: FYI, the question may have been downvoted because it sounds opinionated. Words like "wrong" and "better" are subjective and often lead to questions that are not a good fit for the SO Q&A model.